# iTunes Connect Sales and Trends Report

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect , I selected **Sales and Trends Report** and selected tab **device**. I got the following result. What does this really means ?
Can anyone explain me ?[image]

> Is this shows the number of downloads? If so how can some one download the
>   app from desktop? It only supports **iPhone** and **iPad**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's sales reports and not about programming.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overview shows the number of downloads pro device category excluding updates and previous purchases.

Please note that people can still download your iOS app via iTunes (Desktop) and sync it then with their iOS device.